# Web Worker Plugin Access

Tags: html, plugins, web-worker

Is there a way to either create or somehow access a browser plugin from a web worker instance?  What I am trying to do is to be able to access a Dymo label plugin from a web worker but the navigator object accessible by the web worker does not have the plugin property.

Answer (score 3):

All plugins are instantiated via an object or embed tag. These are creating using the document, which the web worker has no notion of. So as far as I can tell, there is no way to use plugins within a web worker.